# Execute particular file from all user as sudo without password

Tags: python, ubuntu, server, ubuntu-14.04

**my server having a python script file whose user and group is root and i want this file to be executed by all user as sudo without password.**

for this i have added this is in `/etc/sudoers`

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/file.py
```

**but when execute from other user accept root still prompt for password**

**i execute file like this**

```
sudo python /path/to/file.py
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

In `sudoers`, the command `/path/to/file.py` is specified, not `python`.

Execute the command as follow:

```
sudo /path/to/file.py
```

NOTE: Make sure the `/path/to/file.py` is an executable (have proper permission set, containing shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/python ...`))